# TabInFocus Show CommandButton

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, tab, tabpanel

I have a VF page with a requirement to show a commandbutton only for a specific tab. Can I do this with a {!TabInFocus} method? I want to show the 'Add Contact' button only when the Contacts tab is currently selected.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="AccountPricingRanges" sidebar="false" action="{!onloadmethod}" showheader="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Business Profile for {!acc.Name}">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!acc.id}"><p>Back to {!acc.name}</p></apex:outputLink>
        <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact" action="{!addContact}" immediate="true"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Add Timeslot" action="{!addTimeslot}" immediate="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:tabPanel value="{!TabInFocus}">    

                <apex:tab label="Contacts" labelWidth="180" styleClass="label">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="con"> <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="cnt"/>

                        <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                            <apex:commandlink value="Remove" action="{!removeContact}" immediate="true">
                                <!-- Pass the row number to the controller so that we know which row to remove -->
                                <apex:param name="index" value="{!cnt}"/>
                            </apex:commandlink> 
                            <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>              
                        </apex:column>  

                        <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!con.LastName}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!con.email}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!con.phone}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:tab>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class AccountPricingRanges {

    public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}
    Id accountid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('id');

    public void onloadmethod(){
        contacts = [Select FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone
                 FROM Contact
                 WHERE AccountId =:accountid
                 ORDER BY FirstName ASC];
        timeslots = [Select Name, Day_of_Week__c, End_Time__c, Start_Time__c
                     FROM Franchise_Timeslot__c
                     WHERE Franchisee__c =:accountid
                     ORDER BY Day_of_Week__c ASC];
    }

    String tabInFocus = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('tab');
    public String getTabInFocus() {
        return tabInFocus;
    }
    public void setTabInFocus( String s ) {
        this.tabInFocus = s;
    }


    public List<Contact> getcontacts() {
        contacts = [Select FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Contact_Type__c
                 FROM Contact
                 WHERE AccountId =:accountid
                 ORDER BY FirstName ASC];
        return contacts;
    }
```

Comment: You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you trim your code and markup down to just what is necessary to illustrate the issue. Your post contains a massive amount of both for a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ontabenter=""` and `ontableave` attributes on apex:tab, to register the current tab and in your button, you can check if the tab is selected.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!doAnything}" name="tabSelected" rerender="buttons">
    <apex:param assignto="{!contactTabSelected}" name="selected" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:pageBlockButtons id="buttons">
    <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact" action="{!addContact}" immediate="true"
                        rendered="{!contactTabSelected}"/>

<apex:tab label="Contacts" labelWidth="180" styleClass="label"
          ontabenter="tabSelected(true);"
          ontableave="tabSelected(false);">
```

Controller

```
public Boolean contactTabSelected { get; set; }

public void doAnything() {
    //doNothing
}
```

right now I'm not sure if you even need the doAnything method, please try it and give feedback. All I know is you [can skip the action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm), but I'm not sure if params will be passed .

Comment: This is what I found regarding you inFocus question: https://force201.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/keeping-track-of-the-selected-tab-of-an-apextabpanel-in-the-controller/

Comment: ontableave might cause some unexpected behavioir: `The JavaScript invoked if the ontableave event occurs--that is, if a component outside the tab becomes in focus.` If it doesn't work, you could just only use ontabenter on every tab, to keep track of the selected tab and pass their name to the action method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried this and it did not work. The 'Add Contacts' tab does not display at all.